# Merging Columns in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with two columns A and B. I need to merge these columns and have the result be separated by commas. For example:

`Column A | Column B`
    `1          2`

Would become

`Column C`

`1,2`

If possible I would like this to be done with VBA or an excel formula executed by VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take an initial range (defined as rng) cycle through all the rows in this range outputting the contents of column A and B in that row to column C in the same row.

```
set rng = Range(cells(1,1), cells(activesheet.UsedRange.Rows,1))
for each cell in rng
    cell.offset(0,2) = cell & "," & cell.offset(0,1)
next cell
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excel formula

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,",", B1)
```

Answer (score 0):

=A1&","&B1 would also work